# Difference between ls -l and ll?

Tags: command-line, scripts, ls

I'm relatively new to programming as a whole and some tutorials have been telling me to use `ls -l` to look at files in a directory and others have been saying `ll`. I know that `ls` is a short list, but is there a difference between the other two?

Comment: You can inspect how your *sh shell interprets any command with `type [command]`. `type ll` results in `ll is aliased to 'ls -alF'` in my setup.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is located in your `.bashrc`:

```
alias ll='ls -al'
```

By taking a look at the manual pages for the command `ls`, you can see what those two attributes accomplish together:

1. `-a`: do not ignore entries starting with `.`.
2. `-l`: use a long listing format.

So you can understand that `ls -l` would ignore any entry starting with `.`. That's their only difference.

**EDIT:**

Let me note, that, as commented, the `ll` alias differs from installation to installation. In case you are wondering what's yours, please open up a terminal and enter:

```
alias ll
```

This will show you how `ll` is set. You can then look up the additional attributes by typing:

```
man ls
```

Comment: I have `ll is aliased to 'ls -l'`... The alias is copied over from the skeleton files so what people have depends on *when* they installed.

Comment: I have `ls='ls --color=auto'`, `ll='ls -lh'`.  Ubuntu 14.04 ships `/etc/skel/.bashrc` with `ls='ls --color=auto'` `ll='ls -alF`, but that's horrible.  I use `ll` when I want sizes/dates/perms, `ll -a` if I also want dotfiles.

Comment: I also use `alias l=ll`, handy in case I miss a key.

Comment: I've got `alias ll = ls -alF` if this helps anyone.

Comment: More generally, `type ll` will tell you what `ll` is, regardless of whether it's an alias, bash function, or command found in the PATH.

Comment: For your explanation of `-a`, you might want to put `.` in backticks so it's more visible.

Comment: Yes, I've done it.

Comment: A small point: you may want to consider replacing lowercase `a` with uppercase `A`. This will avoid listing `.` and `..`, which are usually not useful. Hence, `ls -Al` or `alias ll='ls -Al'`. If you prefer long options, this is equivalent to `ls -l --almost-all`.

Answer (score 7):

`ll` is a common alias for `ls -l`. It is a part of the default `.bashrc`, with a couple more options:

```
$ grep 'alias ll' /etc/skel/.bashrc
alias ll='ls -alF'
```